# Webpack : bundle only dynamically loaded modules at build time

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack project with the following structure:

[image]

At build time; webpack is able load a module based on an environment variable (src/index.js):

```
const projectMode = process.env.PROJECTMODE
const aMode = require('../dynamic-modules/'+projectMode).default
console.log("oh : " + aMode.mykey);
```

It works fine. But, the generated `bundle.js` contains all the modules from the `dynamic-modules` folder :

```
...
    var e = {
        468: (e,o,r)=>{
            "use strict";
            r.r(o),
            r.d(o, {
                default: ()=>t
            });
            const t = {
                mykey: "world"
            }
        }
        ,
        927: (e,o,r)=>{
            "use strict";
            r.r(o),
            r.d(o, {
                default: ()=>t
            });
            const t = {
                mykey: "app"
            }
        }
        ,
        191: (e,o,r)=>{
            var t = {
                "./bar": 468,
                "./bar.js": 468,
                "./foo": 927,
                "./foo.js": 927
            };
            function n(e) {
...
```

After some research, I found out that webpack's require [generates a context module](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/).

> It contains references to all modules in that directory that can be
> required with a request matching the regular expression. The context
> module contains a map which translates requests to module ids.

**Q:** How can I bundle only the dynamically loaded module at build time ?